# Which metric to use in an ordering problem? auPR / ROC / Lift?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, roc, ranking, precision-recall

I need to order `Users` from most likely to perform a binary action `X` in the next `n` days, to the least likely.
To solve the problem I'm training a `XGBoost` classifier and ordering the `Users` by the predicted probability.
The probablity itself doesn't matter, only that the order is correct.

What would be a good method for evaluating this model?

I thought about splitting the data to percentiles and checking the `lift` in each percentile when I expect to see a higher `lift` so the percentile increases.
Problems with this approach - No "one number" metric, can't evaluate across different datasets.

Thought about using `auPR` but I'm not sure what exactly the `auPR` number means.
I read [here](https://liorpachter.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/reproducibility-vs-usability/) that its `...The probability that if a “positive” edge is selected from the ranked list of the method, then an edge above it on the list will be “positive”`

- Can someone explain why this actually means what it says?
- Is this the most fit metric to optimize in my case?
- Other suggestions?

Comment: Nice question. +1 A lot of intuition from classification and regression is not terribly useful when ranking as it perplexes things.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a ranking problem. Therefore it would be more relevant to look at metrics like the [(normalised) Discounted Cumulative Gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain#Normalized_DCG), [Precision@K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Precision_at_K) and other [information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) performance metrics. Ranking is a very different beast compared to both regression and classification; I would suggest one to first read upon information retrieval a bit to built some intuition. In the modelling task described, users are the documents to be retrieved. I have found reading a bit upon [Bradley-Terry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model) models helpful as they address a somewhat similar problem but taking an approach that is conceptually closer to a "standard probabilistic classification" modelling task. Another thing that helped things "click" for me was the difference between list-wise and pair-wise metrics; the paper by Li on [A Short Introduction to Learning to Rank](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/transinf/E94.D/10/E94.D_10_1854/_pdf/-char/ja) was a very good intro on the matter.

You mention XGBoost; XGBoost natively supports [rank-related learning objectives](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) as well as evaluation metrics like the NDCG and other rank-related indicators so it should play nicely to the requirements of this task. The XGBoost GitHub repo has a [ranking tutorial](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/rank) that should help you getting started.

Comment: BTW, welcome to the CV community!